# Lags while using windows hooks

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, mouselistener

I try to track mouse with code like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HHOOK hMouseHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != NULL)
        printf("X: %d  Y: %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, 0, 0);
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}
```

And this works mostly good except one case. When I click on app console window mouse become very laggy. CPU usage is ok, and I can hit "enter" to "unfreeze" mouse. I can't figure out what I messed up.

Comment: Try to use a different channel for logging, like `OutputDebugString`. MFC provides the [TRACE macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/mfc-debugging-techniques#BKMK_The_TRACE_macro) that does that and provides `printf`-style formatting as well.

Comment: You saved my day. In fact I don't need printing to console. I removed printf and it works good.